# cakephp 3 nginx index.php url rewrite configuration

Tags: nginx, cakephp-3.0

Would like to figure what I am missing for /index.php to work with below config:

Fresh install: Ubuntu 16.04 / Nginx 1.10 / CakePHP 3.3.4

http://dev.test.com/ - good

http://dev.test.com/pages/home - good

http://dev.test.com/pages/test - expected, missing template

http://dev.test.com/something - expected, Error: SomethingController could not be found.

http://dev.test.com/index.php - bad since index.php exists, Error: Index.phpController could not be found.

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.test.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.test.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;

    root /home/andras/sites/dev.test.com/public/webroot/;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name dev.test.com;

    location / {
            index index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the reason you want to hit the index.php page? :)

Comment: no specfic reason for index.php. Always used apache, seemed strange nginx its not loading it as the index.oho file is there...  :)